# AndEngine setPosition inside onManagedUpdate

Tags: android, andengine

I am reading learning andengine book https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Martin_Varga_Learning_AndEngine?id=ww9_BAAAQBAJ.

Try to manually execute setPosition on Player inside onManagedUpdate scene class

Here is my code. For example

```
player.getY()=100 
platform.getFirst().getY()=200
player.getHeight=50



@Override
protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
    // in this position player.getY always 100 evertime onManagedUpdate is called even I already set up player.setPosition like below
    if (player.getY() < platforms.getFirst().getY()) {
        float x = platforms.getFirst().getX();
        float y= platforms.getFirst().getY() + player.getHeight() / 2;
        player.setPosition(x, y);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the player.getY() is back to 100 everytime onManagedUpdate is called even I already set player.setPosition(x,y) inside the managedUpdate

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

In your above assigments, you are using player.getY() = 100; if you want to asign a value to Y coordinate use player.setY(100f); to set a property use set() methods and to get some property value use get() methods.

Change you assigments to this:

```
player.setY(100f);
platform.getFirst().setY(200f);
player.setHeight(50f);
```

Use float values.

Comment: I use player.getY()=100 to inform that Y value before onManaged update is 100. I don't mean to set the Y value become 100. Sorry to confuse you. How to edit my question above to make it clear ?

Comment: Ok! Sorry! I was confused due is not in a comment. How are you declaring the player object to use it in onManagedUpdate method? I don't know about how have you declared it, but try using "this" instead of player or declare above onManagedUpdate Player player = this.